# Why Diaspora Federation pod communication protocol shares AES keys over asymmetric encrypted channels?

Tags: rsa, aes, key-exchange

As I was looking over the diaspora federation Magic Envelope [documentation](https://diaspora.github.io/diaspora_federation/federation/encryption.html), I noticed something weird:

```
{
  "aes_key": "...",
  "encrypted_magic_envelope": "..."
}
```

After some thought, I realized that it uses asymmetric cryptography to send a symmetric key. But other technologies such as TOR or OTR, or even Signal, perform Diffie-Hellman over an asymmetrically-encrypted channel.

So I wonder, why choose to do that? Do they choose that due to the stateless nature of the HTTP protocol used in the Salmon Protocol on top of a [webfinger](https://diaspora.github.io/diaspora_federation/discovery/webfinger.html) communication? If yes, what affected the decision to do that?

Comment: Does the context limit to one-way communication? That would make asymmetric encryption of a symmetric key the best remaining option. It lacks forward secrecy (unless something not shown in the question makes the asymmetric key ephemeral) and replay protection (unless something not shown in the question offers that).

Comment: Well I guess the communication are post based, I post something to somewhere encrypted. The communications used on Diaspora* are based on webfinger (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebFinger) protocol.